# Does ZFC prove every extensional well-founded out-tree translate into a set?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $T$ be an extensional well-founded [out-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)), where well-founded refers to absence of infinite branches, and extensional refers to absence of two isomorphic full subtrees of $T$ whose root nodes are connected to a common node in $T$. By *full* subtree of $T$ its meant a subtree of $T$ that has every branch of $T$ stemming from its root node being a branch of it! For any node $n$ in $T$ we call the full subtree of $T$ stemming from it as $Tree^T(n)$

We define a translation function $f$ from nodes of $T$ to a set $x$ as:

$f(root( T)) = x \\ f(n)=f(m) \iff Tree^T(n) \approx Tree^T(m)$

Where $\approx$ stand for isomorphism between trees.

Now we define a graph $G(f)$ on $range(f)$ that has a directed edge between any elements of $range(f)$ if and only if an element of the pre-image (under $f$) of one of them is connected by an edge to an element of the pre-image (under $f$) of the other node, and the direction of that edge in $G(f)$ is the same as that between those two connected nodes in $T$.

Now $f$ would be called a translation from tree $T$ to set $x$ if and only if $G(f)$ is the membership relation on the transitive closure set of $x$.

So we'd say: a tree $T$ translates into a set $x$ if and only if a translation $f$ exists between them.

> Does $\sf ZFC$ prove that "every extensional well-founded out-tree translates into a set"?

> If we add the above as an axiom to $\sf ZF$, would that get to interpret  $\sf AC$?

Comment: What's an out-tree?

Comment: Isn't it better to define extensional in the standard way?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I know of a definition of extensional graphs. Which of course is not the same as extensionality of trees I'm speaking about here. Can you refer me to the standard definition of extensional trees.

Comment: We say that $R$ is an extensional relation (on some $X$) if $x=y\iff\forall z(z\mathrel{R}x\leftrightarrow z\mathrel{R}y)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, how that conform to the case of extensionality of trees spoken about here? I mean what is $R$ here? If it means $x R y$ iff there is a directed path from $y$ to $x$, then we can have multiple end nodes and all of them would be $R$-empty.

Comment: I suppose that it means that if you look at the nodes below $x$ and the nodes below $y$, these are not isomorphic subtrees.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes but that's not equivalent to extensionality of trees that I defined here. What you are speaking about applies to extensionality of graphs. This is different.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, to make matters clear, extensionality of trees as spoken about here means that no two distinct branches of the tree are isomorphic, where a branch is a path from the root node to an end node of the tree.

Comment: @AsafKaragila so the reason why I didn't use the convensional definition of "extensional" relation for extensional trees, is because it would render all extensional trees into lines (paths) so it needs to be weakened in order to be applicable to trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every extensional and well-founded relation on a set is isomorphic to a unique transitive set. This is the set-version of Mostowski's collapse lemma (the general version on classes requires that the relation is also set-like: every point has only a set that is "in relation with it", e.g. the class of ordinals and the transitive set is now a transitive class).

So $\sf ZF$ proves that every extensional and well-founded tree is isomorphic to a set. Therefore your questions are answered yes and no respectively.

Comment: Nice! I think the answer must include that every *extensional* (in my sense) tree is convertable into an extensional well founded relation, and by then the result goes through. The proof of that is easy since we can partition the nodes of a tree after isomorphism of full substrees stemming from the nodes, then easily construct a relation on all of those parts after the edge relation and so get our extensional well founded relation

Comment: Given this answer, it appears to me that any well founded out-tree can be translated into set!

Comment: @ do you mean "every extensional well founded relation *that is a set*" is isomorphic to....

Comment: What do you mean with the last comment?

Comment: I mean the word *relation* can be a proper class, for example $\in$ can be an extensional well founded relation, so it cannot be isomorphic ot a set, I think you are speaking of relations that are $sets$.

Comment: No, the general statement is that if $R$ is a relation on $X$ that is well-founded and *set-like* (for all $x$, $\{y\mid y\mathrel{R}x\}$ is a set) then it is isomorphic to a transitive class ordered by $\in$. Of course it's not isomorphic to a set.

Comment: so the proper statement of the *set* version of this lemma is: every extensional well founded relation *on a set $X$* is isomorphic to a unique transitive *set*. the "on a set $X$" is important to be added here.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll add that to clarify.